# html image won't scale downwards

Tags: html, css

I wrote a Django application, where different (random) online images are put in :

```
<img src={{j.5}} width="150" height="150" border="0">
```

It works fine for most of the images, but some of them, which have high dimensions, do not show on my page. I tried with CSS:

```
img {max-width: 100%;max-height: 100%;}
```

But is not functioning. Since the pictures are selcted randomly, I want to make image to scale downwards. For example this image won't resize:

```
http://www.civitas.al/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/atentati-2111.jpg
```

Any idea?

Comment: Is it just `img` tags in the document? Or more?

Comment: There are more tags, img tag is inside a <td rowspan="3"> tag, it is a table of rows, where every row is: text, image

Answer (score 0):

Technically (you did not provide pictures), using consistent `width` and `max-width` both as CSS styles will remove possible conflicts between the DOM's idea of tag width and element width. This means

```
<img src={{j.5}} />
```

And

```
img {width: 150px; height: 150px; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; border: 0;}
```

are working for me.

Comment: What if you give `img` another style called `display: inline-block`?

Comment: I'm asking that because your pic shows scaling *up* instead of *down* like you said.

Comment: It works in a simple html file, but I can not figure out why it doesn't work sometimes in my Django template

Comment: Can't help you like that buddy, you gave us virtually nothing to work on, especially when what you gave us actually works :/

Comment: You already helped me - clarified that it was not resizing problem (very little experience with html). In pages where I looked for was a mess, the same .jpg file showed more then once, so I took the second or the third one and it is OK now.